# Pthreads, fread(), and printf(): Getting random D4's in my string

Tags: c, pthreads, printf, fread

## The Scoop:

I am creating a method that runs through a lengthy file in chunks: using `pthreads`. I am calling `fread()` to read the file in this sort of fashion:

```
fread( thread_data[i].buffer, 1, 50, f )
/*
 thread_data is a data structure for each thread (hence i)
 buffer is in thread_data as an array of length 50
 */
```

I am then directly calling a print statement to see what each thread is doing, as a weird pattern was showing up in some of the parts that I was printing. **Namely, my print statement would look something like this**:

```
 this is suppose to be 50 characters, but it is only a fewgD4
```

**That `D4` directly above** is what I have my question on. Every thread that I make, at the end of the string, we are printing `D4`, and in this case, followed by a `g`. Other times, it is followed by a d, and most commonly a �. Now, [I did read the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29) on this character, which states:

> replacement character used to replace an unknown or unrepresentable character

## My question:

What kind of an error am I running into? Why is the end of each read statement containing unknown characters, especially the weird `gD4` guy?

## Aside:

I am trying to make a function in [c](/questions/tagged/c) that utilizes pthreads to find the frequency of each word in a file, in case anyone was wondering. These weird characters were showing up in my list,  which is something that I find slightly unpleasent. Finally, [don't bother linking me to the Obligaroty Unicode article](http://kunststube.net/encoding/), I am already aware of it, and the characters are not outside of what I am working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings you are printing out are not null-terminated — `fread()` does not null-terminate its output, it simply reads in as many raw bytes as you asked for (or fewer).  So when you print out your buffer, your print function is walking past the end of the data and printing out whatever garbage memory comes after the buffer, which in your case just happens to be `gD4`.

You need to either explicitly null-terminate your buffer; or, if your print function supports it, tell it exactly how many characters to print.  Either way, you need to save the return value from `fread` to know how many characters you read.  For example:

```
int n = fread(thread_data[i].buffer, 1, 50, f);
if (n < 0) /* Handle error */ ;

// Explicitly add a null terminator -- make sure the buffer has room for it!
thread_data[i].buffer[n] = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response last night. If you don't mind, I was wondering if I could pick your brain on this a little further. That is, is there a way to grab something like `(thread_data[i].buffer)[9]`?